# How to gradually set every items from a list as an innerHTML/textContent using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, setinterval

I want to display all items from a list as an innerHTML every second at my HTML page using javascript.
Here's my code:

```
--------------------HTML--------------------

<text id="firstWoman" class="text" x="380" y="110" fill="red" font-size="56">Mary</text>

--------------------JS--------------------

let W1 = document.getElementById("firstWoman");
let W1_list = ["Mary", "Anne", "Jessica"];

let W1_timeline = setInterval(function(){
    for(let w of W1_list){
        W1.textContent = w;
    }
    if (let w in W1_list> w.length ){
        clearInterval(W1_timeline);
        }
}, 1000);
```

similar way doesn't work either:

```
let W1 = document.getElementById("firstWoman");
let W1_list = ["Mary", "Anne", "Jessica"];
let w = W1_list[0];

let W1_timeline = setInterval(function(){
        W1.textContent = w++;

    if (let w in W1_list> w.length ){
        clearInterval(W1_timeline);
        }
}, 1000);
```

This works for numbers but not for strings apparently. Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code.

```
for(let w of W1_list){
    W1.textContent = w;
}
```

Here you're looping over the complete W1_list array in a rush.

You need to use a global counter which determines what element out of the array you want to display.
Then you're able to assign it to the text element by:

```
W1.textContent = W1_list[counter];
```

To clear the timer if you reached the end of the array, you need to increment the counter and compare it to the length of the array.

```
  if (counter == W1_list.length) {
    clearInterval(W1_timeline);
  }
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
let W1 = document.getElementById("firstWoman");
let W1_list = ["Mary", "Anne", "Jessica"];
let counter = 0;
let W1_timeline = setInterval(function() {
  W1.textContent = W1_list[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter == W1_list.length) {
    clearInterval(W1_timeline);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<text id="firstWoman" class="text" x="380" y="110" fill="red" font-size="56">Mary</text>
```

Comment: That works just the way I need, thank you very much.